# Any way to tag Windows processes recursively?

Tags: windows, process, tagging

Currently, I'm using environment variables to do just that. But, when processes get started using cmd.exe instead of cygwin's bash.exe, I cannot read their environment variables easily via /proc any more. Apart from that, there is also a race condition between reading a process' environment variables and killing it where the process gets replaced in the meantime with another process having the same process id.

Another solution would possibly be process groups, assuming the group IDs will be propagated to child processes and that I can somehow kill stuff explicitly by using the process group id. However, this is not applicable to processes that already have a process group id. Or can I give them a second group id?

A last-resort solution would be to assume that the parent process keeps running and clears up childs. This is a pretty risky assumption however, and here again we have a race condition between identifying child processes and the actual act of killing them via their PID.

Is there any tooling provided by Windows to achieve just what I'm trying to do? Not necessarily using pgids or env vars.

Comment: `process group id` - this is what ?! unclear about what you asking, but may be you want [Job Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: Good hint, but no: "Child processes created using Win32_Process.Create are not associated with the job."